# Sum of the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question:** $1^2+2\cdot2^2+3^2+2\cdot4^2 + \dotsb =\frac{n(n+1)^2}{2}$, when $n$ is even. Now find the sum when $n$ is odd.

My approach was, just put $n$ as $n-1$ or $n+1$ in the sum formula.
I supposed it correct, as it is in the case of sum of $n$ numbers, $1+2+3 + \dotsb =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$  if $n$ is odd here, to get the sum when the last term is even I just put $n$ as $n+1$ or $n-1$.

The correct answer is $\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}$. Please explain where I am wrong and why, and what should be the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily have observed *that* you were wrong, if not *why* you were wrong, by trying an odd number or two: for instance, with $n=3$,

$$1^2+2\cdot2^2+3^2=1+8+9=18\ne24=\frac{3\cdot16}2=\frac{(2+1)\big((2+1)+1\big)^2}2\;.$$

The problem here is that the odd-numbered and even-numbered terms follow different rules: the $(2n+1)$-st term is $(2n+1)^2$, while the $2n$-th term is $\color{crimson}2(2n)^2$. Adding an extra odd term adds a square; adding an extra even term adds *twice* a square. The ‘steps’ are of different kinds; you shouldn’t expect the same formula to hold when the last step is a square as when it’s twice a square. In fact we have

$$1^2+2\cdot2^2+\ldots+2(2k)^2=\frac{(2k)(2k+1)^2}2$$

when the last term is the even number $2k$, so when we add the next odd term we get

$$\begin{align*}
1^2+2\cdot2^2+\ldots+2(2k)^2+(2k+1)^2&=\frac{(2k)(2k+1)^2}2+(2k+1)^2\\
&=\frac{(2k)(2k+1)^2+2(2k+1)^2}2\\
&=(k+1)(2k+1)^2\;.
\end{align*}$$

If we let $n=2k+1$, so that $k=\frac{n-1}2$, we have

$$1^2+2\cdot2^2+\ldots+n^2=\left(\frac{n-1}2+1\right)n^2=\frac{n^2(n+1)}2\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

In order to simplify notation, I will refer to the summation of the first $n$ terms as $f(n)$ and I will refer to the $n^{th}$ term itself as $a_n$.

That is to say, $f(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i$ and $a_n = \begin{cases} n^2&\text{if}~n~\text{is odd}\\ 2n^2&\text{if}~n~\text{is even}\end{cases}$

You are told ahead of time that that $f(n)=\frac{n(n+1)^2}{2}$ for even $n$.

In the case that $n$ is odd, we have $f(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i = a_n + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i=a_n+f(n-1)~~~~~\color{gray}{(\dagger)}$

Now... to simplify further, we use the fact that with $n$ odd, we have $n-1$ is even and then we know how to express $f(n-1)$ as it is the summation of an even number of terms.  We also know how to express $a_n$.  Continuing then, we have:

$\color{grey}{(\dagger)}~~~~~\dots=a_n+f(n-1)=a_n + \frac{(n-1)n^2}{2} = n^2+\frac{(n-1)n^2}{2} = \frac{2n^2+(n-1)n^2}{2} = \frac{(n+1)n^2}{2}$